# Which one is the right procedure to create the react native app. create-react-native-app MyReactNative or react-native init MyReactNative?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, react-native, command-prompt

I am new to the React native app. I am integrating my native iOS Framework in the sample react native app. When I try to create a sample app, I saw two option to create and I have added below:

**1: npm install -g create-react-native-app:**

After installing NodeJS and NPM successfully in my system I have used this command: **npm install -g create-react-native-app**

For creating the project I have followed this command: **create-react-native-app MyReactNative**

**Ref:** https://www.tutorialspoint.com/react_native/react_native_environment_setup.htm

I can able to use”user_framework!” In the pod file and added swift native dependencies, as well as a static library of react native dependencies and I can able to run the app.

**2.react-native init MyReactNative :**

I have followed this command for creating the project: **react-native init MyReactNative**

But when I use the  ”user_framework!” In the pod file and added swift native dependencies I can not able to run the app. I am getting the dyld: Library not loaded for swift dependencies.

Ref: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/04/the-beauty-of-react-native-building-your-first-ios-app-with-javascript-part-1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Both option use for create react native app.**

- First option used for **expo** react native app.

  create-react-native-app MyReactNative
- Normally, used for create react-native application.

  react-native init MyReactNative

and for this error: dyld: Library not loaded for swift dependencies.

```
1) first check **framework** compatible with iphone simulator.

2) Drag and drop **user_framework** in your project navigation. Link framework 
   and Library added this library.

3) In Xcode go to Project -> General -> Embedded Binary -> Add user_framework. 
 (if xcode 10.1 or below) or Project > Framworks,Libraries,and Embeded content 
  (xcode 11 or above )

4) Make sure that in Build Phases tab Link Binary with Libraries (have 1 item) 
  and Embed Frameworks (have 1 item) do exist.
```